# how log files are created in berkelydb java edition db base api

Tags: berkeley-db

we are using berkeleydb java edition db base api, we have already read/write CDRFile of 9 lack rows with transaction and without transaction implementing secondary database concept the issues we are getting are as follows:-

with transaction----------size of database environment 1.63gb which is due to no. of log files created each of  10 mb.

without transaction-------size of database environment 588mb and here only one log file is created which is of 10mb. so we want to know how this happens..

how log files are created and what is meant of using transaction and not using transaction in db environment and what are this db files  _*db.001,*_db.002,_*db.003,*_db.004,__db.005  and log files like log.0000000001.....plz reply soon

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question was already answered here [what are log files and why they are created during transaction in berkeleydb core api(dbapi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648463/what-are-log-files-and-why-they-are-created-during-transaction-in-berkeleydb-core).

From your description it actually looks like you're using Berkeley DB core, not Java Edition. __db.001 through __db.005 are the shared region system environment files. The environment files are described [here](http://bit.ly/oJPV7A). The log.* files are the transaction log files. The transaction log files are described in the answer referenced above.

These types of questions can often be more easily/quickly answered on the Berkeley DB [forum](http://bit.ly/eIREhr) on OTN.

Regards,

Dave